# Take in multiple user input values using Qt QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, input, qtablewidget

I'm trying to make a basic UI for taking in user input and displaying the output, using Qt. I just started working with UIs, so this might seem trivial. I have to take in 3 sets of inputs, where each set consists of 90 integer values. Think of each set as a 2d array of 30 by 3. I'm trying to see what the best way to handle this user input would be in Qt. I have used Qt to work on a .ui file and the link below is of a screenshot of what it should look like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KedP7.png

To be more specific, I have used the QTableWidget to create the table itself. My question now is how do I access user input from each cell of the table and store it into an array for that whole table?

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`QTableWidget::item(int row, int column)` returns the item at position (row, column).
Row can be between 0 and `QTableWidget::rowCount()` – 1, column between 0  and `QTableWidget::columnCount()` – 1

`QTableWidgetItem::text()` returns the items text.

Create a function, which reads alls items and add them to an array in a loop, connect the pressed-signal of the Enter-Button with this function.

If you only want to read updated items: the `QTableWidget::itemChanged()` signal sends the item, which was updated.  `QTableWidget::indexFromItem()` returns the index of the item, so you can update your array.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. (I dont have the privilege to comment):

I use a **help_index**  which basically numbers the elements from left to right. Everytime a cell is edited (return pressed) the next element is selected (the +1 in the help_index line). If the last index is reached i focus the OK button.

You might read data at:

- Input time (test_STR1)
- The OK button is pressed (test_STR2 Set the auto default on the button: [How to make a QPushButton pressable for enter key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887938/how-to-make-a-qpushbutton-pressable-for-enter-key))

Tab Function:

```
    void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_cellChanged(int row, int column)
    {
        QString test_STR1 = ui->tableWidget->item(row,column)->text();   // is string
        qDebug(QString("OnCell %1,%2:%3").arg(column).arg(row).arg(test_STR).toLatin1());
        // EG int array[rows][columns];
        // QList<QStringList<QString>>  (equivalent to: QList<QList<QString>>)
        int columncount , rowcount, help_index,nextRow, nextColimn;
        columncount = ui->tableWidget->columnCount();
        rowcount = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
        help_index = column + row*columncount +1;
        if(help_index < columncount*rowcount)
        {
            nextRow = help_index / columncount;
            nextColimn = help_index % columncount;
            ui->tableWidget->setCurrentCell(nextRow,nextColimn);
        }
        else
        {
            ui->pushButton_OK->setFocus();
        }
    }
```

Ok_button:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_OK_clicked()
{
    for(int i=ui->tableWidget->columnCount()-1;i>=0;i--)
        for(int j=ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            QString test_STR2 = ui->tableWidget->item(j,i)->text();
            qDebug(QString("OnOk %1,%2:%3").arg(i).arg(j).arg(test_STR).toLatin1());
        }

}
```