# Press Enter emits buttonClicked on QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, qbuttongroup

I'm using C++ with Qt. I have this problem. I have `QLineBox` (lineBox) and `QButtonGroup` (buttonGroup) with buttons from type `QPushButton`. When I press enter on lineBox, signal `buttonClicked` is emitted for buttonGroup.

lineBox is in `QGraphicView`. This `QGraphicView` is in same layout as buttonGroup. I don't want to emit clickButton when press enter. Any Ideas why this happened?

There is a little difference between my question and this one: [How to make a QPushButton pressable for enter key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887938). It is in initialization of autoDefault property.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Might have something to do with default / autoDefault buttons

Comment: @king_nak AutoDefault was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @VladimirYanakiev please post your solution as answer (even if it's short or super easy), it could help future readers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a QPushButton pressable for enter key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887938/how-to-make-a-qpushbutton-pressable-for-enter-key)

Comment: I'm not quite assure If this answer my question. Although in both cases same properties are used. In my case I pressed enter on LineEdit and emit QPushButton buttonclicked. This question is how to make QPushButton Pressable for  enter key.